# Online Gantt chart

Tags: project-management

I am interested in online "free" platform similar to Microsoft Project which can generate Gantt charts. The main limitation is that ~20 persons should edit the charts. Would you be so kind to suggest a solution, e.g. google documents?

Best regards,
Volodymyr

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of these around.  The one with which I have had most success is [Open Project](https://www.openproject.org/).

This is an open source, collaborative package that meets your requirements.

The basic level, [*"Community"*](https://www.openproject.org/pricing/), level of access is free to use.

Answer (score 3):

A powerful online package is [Project Libre](http://www.projectlibre.com/).

Project Libre is open source and compatible with MS Project files.

This is free if the package is downloaded and run on your own machine.  You can keep your chart files in a shared drive to effectively use it online.

There is a [full cloud version](http://www.projectlibre.com/product/projectlibre-cloud) which is "coming soon", which will run in your browser.  However, this version will not be free.